# AWS API GATEWAY from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I’m trying to deploy an API to be used in Front End. it's work when testing the API alone but it's return CORS error when integrate in Vue app where the error return is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://APIDomain/development/pin'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

i'm using serverless to deploy this API where i have setup the origin allowed in this serverless.yml:

```
service: test-lambda-node
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: development
  region: ap-east-1
  memorySize: 512
  timeout: 15
functions:
  app:
    handler: lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: 'http://localhost:8080'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
            allowCredentials: false
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: 'http://localhost:8080'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
            allowCredentials: false
```

I’m also using wildcard to allowed all type of origin but it's still not work. I also attempted to enable CORS manually in AWS API Gateway console but still not work.
Is there any way for me to allow this API to enable the CORS policy for any origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

CORS headers aren’t being sent from your Vue application.

## Solution

Add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to your Vue app when sending a request to the API.

## Note

Also, set `allowCredentials` in your serverless.yml and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` In your Vue app to `true` if you are using cookies.

## References

Serverless - CORS Survival Guide: https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide

Comment: i have add the header in vue app. but then there was return another error in preflight response

` Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Comment: @KhairulHabib since your application is sending a preflight request you must add  `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to your serverless.yml. The referenced document in my answer explains how to do this in detail—just do a search for “preflight requests” in that document.